# Good way to build a blocking, zero-length queue in Python

Tags: java, python, multithreading, concurrency

In Java, there's `java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue`, a queue with no storage capacity. Threads trying to put/get value always block until another thread tries to get/put a value respectively.

What are good ways to do the same in Python? I.e. I want a way to pass values from a set of one or more threads to another set of one or more threads without a value ever "belonging" to a thread in either group.

Python's `queue.Queue` does not allow the length to be `0`, specifying a non-positive value for the maximum capacity creates an unbounded queue.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Queue.join()` and `Queue.task_done()` to block until the `get()` has completed:

```
class SynchronousQueue(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.q = Queue(1)
        self.put_lock = RLock()

    def get(self):
        value = self.q.get(block=True)
        self.q.task_done()
        return value

    def put(self, item):
        with self.put_lock:
            self.q.put(item, block=True)
            self.q.join()
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the feeling the following might be deadlock city, but would something like the following work?

```
class SynchronousQueue(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ready_to_get = Queue(1)
        self.queue = Queue(1)

    def get(self):
        self.ready_to_get.put('ready', block=True)
        return self.queue.get(block=True)

    def put(self, item):
        self.ready_to_get.get(block=True)
        self.queue.put(item, block=True)
```

A regular queue supports half of what you want (the getter waiting on the putter), so we can try and implement the reverse by blocking the put until a get has started.

Comment: I don't think it changes the behaviour if you made these queues unlimited length but it might be more efficient: it would mean the `ready_to_get.put()` could never block (buts that's alright as the `queue.get()` will still block) and likewise the `queue.put()` wouldn't block but you wouldn't reach it unless something was trying to `get`.

Comment: I wanted to try and account for the situation where there are two getters queued up, but only one writer available. But I think you're right, we're covered by the get anyway.